# How to validate field with input type=time via form control? Used Angular Material

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

Field with input type=time can't validate via form control.
I get error:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'thirdCtrl'

Part of code, which don't handle via Vaildator

```
 <mat-step [stepControl]="thirdFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="thirdFormGroup">    
<mat-form-field formControlName="thirdCtrl">
    <input matInput type="time">
    </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
```

Simple FormGroup for above form

```
this.thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      thirdCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

I suspect error occurs because FormControl try to handle input field with type time, but I don't know how to change this FormControl for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move `formControlName="thirdCtrl"` binding from `<mat-form-field>` to `<input>`, like:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="thirdFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="thirdFormGroup">    
       <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput type="time" formControlName="thirdCtrl">
       </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </form>
</mat-step>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="thirdFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="thirdFormGroup">    
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="time" formControlName="thirdCtrl">
    </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
```