# How to add FormValidation for DatePicker with used Angular Material?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

within the question [How to validate field with input type=time via form control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497508/how-to-validate-field-with-input-type-time-via-form-control-used-angular-materi)

How to validate such datepicker (which haves disabled input field)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="datePickerCtrl" disabled>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

If tag formControlName insert in input, disabled status doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of disabled use readonly.

Answer (score 0):

dont use disabled in html with reactive form insted use darePickerCtrl.disable(). see [this](https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110).
 and date input validation is just like any other input

```
datePickerCtrl= new FormControl('', [
Validators.required,
]);
```